# TFS 2008 MSBuild Dynamic Random Messages?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs, msbuild, message

I have added custom build messages so the Visual Studio GUI shows status messages during the course of a msbuild. I would like to now add something dynamic so I can inject random cute thoughts for the build-watcher.

How could this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write you own task, if you need guidance on how to do so grab a copy of my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286). That is if it is worth the effort for these "*random cute thoughts*" :)